# ipython --pylab vs ipython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

What does `ipython --pylab` exactly do?

Is  `ipython --pylab` **exactly** equivalent to:

```
 > ipython
 > from pylab import *
```

If not, what are the differences?

Say I launch IPython **without** the `--pylab` arguments, how can I bring it to the same state as if I had started it **with** `--pylab`?

Comment: I think the incentive for the `--pylab` flag was to make `ipython` a MATLAB clone, so MATLAB users switching to python/numpy/scipy/matplotlib wouldn't have to deal with `import` statements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`--pylab[=option]` is almost technically equivalent to `%pylab option` as the difference that you cannot un-pylab a `--pylab` kernel, but you can restart a `%pylab` kernel.

`%pylab` is a little more that just `from pylab import *` (see `%pylab?`for a longer explanation), but in short yes it imports a lot of things, but it also hooks event loops (qt, wx, osx...) and set-up some display hooks for matplotlib (the things that magically allow you to get inline graph). Setting the display-hook is closer to something like `sympy.init_printing()` if you wonder.

Note that starting at IPython 1.0 we recommend not to use `--pylab` or `%pylab` (unless you know exactly the implication). We provide `%matplotlib` that only init the display hook. `%pylab` will warn you if it replaced a few object in current namespace, and which ones. This is useful especially for functions like `sum` which do not have the same behavior the behavior with and without pylab and leads to subtle bugs.

We consider now that `--pylab` was a mistake, but that it was still really usefull at the beginning of IPython. We all know that `Explicit is better than implicit` so if you can advise people not to use `%pylab` we would appreciate it, to one day get rid of it.

Extract from %pylab help that give only the import part of pylab:

```
%pylab makes the following imports::

import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

Answer (score 4):

One noticeable difference besides the imports is the interactive plotting, which you can enable dynamically with:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['interactive'] = True
```

Comment: or `ipython --matplotlib` which sets up the backend and makes it interactive, but without importing all the pylab stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `--pylab` option on the command line is equivalent to using the `%pylab` magic. At least that is how I have used it. That also gives you the opportunity to choose plotting backend, i.e. `%pylab inline`, `%pylab qt`, etc.