# Installing packages in base anaconda environment

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, anaconda, package, conda

Oftentimes installing some package causes my whole anaconda distribution to crash. One instance where I faced such issue is when I do:

```
$ ipython --pylab
```

Then, I get

> segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is usually because of some package mismatch/error. To resolve such situations the whole packages has to be re-installed in my anaconda distribution.

Fortunately, I usually take the list of packages that I install in my *base* conda environment using:

```
$ conda list --export > conda_packages.txt
```

So, how can I re-installed all packages at once using this *conda_packages.txt* file? So that I don't have to manually install each package from this file.

Is there a short command line option for achieving this in *nix, particularly in Ubuntu?

Comment: Note that the IPython devs no longer recommend using the `pylab` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528503/2449192

Comment: @darthbith I get this error irrespective of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for some time, I managed to solve this problem with:

```
# assumes that anaconda is installed in ~/anaconda3
conda create -p /home/user/anaconda3/envs --file conda_packages.txt
```

This would install all the packages in `conda_packages.txt` to the *`base`* conda environment.

---

To install it in a particular `env`, use:

```
conda create --name /home/user/anaconda3/envs/<your_env_name> --file conda_packages.txt
```

Comment: For me the command above removed all exisiting enviroment, I had to run `conda update --file conda_packages.txt` to make it updated base